# XAML/WPF: How do I bind a command to a comboboxitem

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox, command

I want to bind a command to a comboboxitem much like a typical command (either application or custom) is bound to a button.  I can't seem to find an example.

EDIT:

The ComboBoxItem exists as part of a ContentControl that also contains a button.  The button has an associated command that works well.  How can I bind a command, in a similar way, to the ComboBoxItem?

```
<!--    Line    -->
<Button x:Name="Line"
    Style="{DynamicResource Button_Title}"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="3"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Content="Line"
    Command="{x:Static local:Ribbon_AC.Custom_RoutedUICommand}"
    CommandParameter="Line"
    Tag="{DynamicResource Line_32}"/>

    <!--    Arc -->
    <ContentControl x:Name="ArcSplit"
            Template="{DynamicResource Control_SplitSmall}"
            Tag="{DynamicResource Arc_20}"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1">

    <ComboBox Name="ComboBox_Arc"
        Style="{DynamicResource ComboBox_Small}"
        Width="{DynamicResource Width_DropDown}">

        <!--    Arc_0   -->
        <ComboBoxItem   x:Name="Arc_0"
                Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItem_Large}"
                Tag="{DynamicResource Arc0_32}"
                Content="Arc 0">

        </ComboBoxItem>
```

Comment: When do you want the command to execute? Do you want to execute the command each time the selected item changes or do you want to be able to change the selected item without triggering the command?

Comment: It's part of a templated split button based on a ComboBox.  I would like it to execute when clicked as well as change the image on the split so that I can just click the button the next time to re-issue the command.  Similar to selecting a background color for a cell in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Foo" Handler="Bar"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks Cannibal.  Turns out it was a scope issue.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the options you can consider putting a Button into the ComboBox's ItemTemplate and change the Button's template to make it look "not like a button at all".

But that is dirty. Maybe you can use Menu instead of ComboBox?

Comment: I tried to do exactly that but there were other considerations.  I think your menu idea may end up being the way to go, again, for any number of reasons.